# Nancy looks for views in wrong project

Tags: c#, .net, owin, nancy

#### Edit

I just downloaded the source code of the tutorial project from GitHub. When I build and run the project, I see that the `Website/Modules/` folder is copied into the `bin/Debug` folder of the `Service` project. But this does not happen when I build my `Service` project.

What could be the reason?

---

I am following the tutorial in [this link](https://blog.sstorie.com/self-hosting-an-angular-2-website-in-a-windows-service/).

I have completed the part until the `index.html` is added and should show `Nancy is working!` when the webpage is loaded.

I had to change the `ViewLocationConventions` to

```
$"../../../Service.Website/Website/Modules/{context.ModuleName}/views/{viewName}"
```

Only then everything works fine with Nancy 1.x version. Why doesn't it work when I use

```
$"Website/Modules/{context.ModuleName}/views/{viewName}"
```

like in the tutorial?

And when I use Nancy 2.x, it cannot find the view file at all. No matter what I set `ViewLocationConventions` to.

i.e., it still looks for the `Website/Modules/Root/view/index.html` file in the `Service` project.

Any other workaround, other than moving the view files itself to the `Service` project?

---

**Quick background of the tutorial:**

The solution has 2 projects `Service` and `Service.Website` as shown below.

1. `Service` is a Topshelf service that hosts a server that runs the web project
2. `Service.Website` is a web project using Owin and Nancy

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `Nancy` package added to `Service.Website` but not to `Service`?

Comment: Yes `Nancy` package is installed only to the `Service.Website` project. When I use Nancy 1.x version, everything works fine. If I use Nancy 2.x version, then I get the problem.

Comment: in your solution explorer, right click on `Website/Modules/` and click properties. In the copy to output directory setting change it to copy always or copy if newer

Comment: When I click on properties, I get only `Folder Name`. There is no `Output Directory` setting.

Comment: @hellyale Thanks for the hint. The `Copy to Output Directory` option is only available for files. Once I set it to the index.html, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hellyale's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753356/nancy-looks-for-views-in-wrong-project?noredirect=1#comment82472874_47753356), I had to set the `Copy to Output Directory` of the `index.html` file to `Copy always`.

This then copies the file to the `bin/Debug` folder and `Nancy` is now able to find the view.